# Divs wont fit inside their container and they have added pixels.

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a bunch of divs that display inside a fixed size container div. Using javascript I can create the number of divs I want. My issue is that the divs aren't fitting in the container horizontally or vertically. The container div should have a height and width of 1000px which I set in css instead it has a height and width of 1002px which I realised after inspecting the page. The smaller squares are also adding 2px to the height and width which means anything more than a 1x1 grid won't fit in the container. I'm really not sure why this is happening though. Any help would be appreciated.

Link to jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/wrjo38t5/

HTML:

```
<body>

    <button type="button">Reset</button>

    <div id= "container">



    </div>

    <script src="jQuery.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  border: 1px dashed black;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 1000px;
  font-size: 0;
}
.square{
  float: left;
  font-size: 0;
  border: 1px dashed red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var gridSize = prompt("Enter size of grid:");
gridSize = Number(gridSize);



createGrid(gridSize);

function createGrid(gridSize){
    //setting up variables
    var newSize = 1000/gridSize;
    var j = 1;
    var i = 1;
    var cont = document.getElementById('container');

    //loop to add a column square
    while(i<=gridSize){

        var sketchSquare = document.createElement('div');
        sketchSquare.className= "square";
        sketchSquare.style.width= newSize + "px";
        sketchSquare.style.height= newSize + "px";
        cont.appendChild(sketchSquare);
        //if statement to add new row
        if (i === gridSize && j < gridSize) {
            j++;
            i = 0;

        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The css `border` adds to the width and height.
Try using `outline` instead:

```
div {
  outline: 1px dashed black;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 1000px;
  font-size: 0;
}
.square{
  float: left;
  font-size: 0;
  outline: 1px dashed red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vny85wnh/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) and set it to border-box so the border is taken into account for the width calculation

```
.square {
    /* your other styles omitted */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```